# How to return and get the sum of object properties based on given filters?

Tags: javascript, filter

I have the following object.

```
var data = [
{"Name":"ABC","Dept":"First","FY":"2016","Quarter":"1","Month":"April","Total":"100"},
{"Name":"ABC","Dept":"Second","FY":"2017","Quarter":"2","Month":"May","Total":"200"},
{"Name":"ABC","Dept":"First","FY":"2016","Quarter":"1","Month":"June","Total":"150"},
{"Name":"DEF","Dept":"First","FY":"2016","Quarter":"1","Month":"April","Total":"200"},
{"Name":"DEF","Dept":"Second","FY":"2017","Quarter":"2","Month":"May","Total":"100"},
{"Name":"DEF","Dept":"First","FY":"2016","Quarter":"1","Month":"June","Total":"500"}
]
```

I want to filter on the abve object to get:

a. I want to `return Total based on my filters`(ex: If I give Name as ABC, Dept as First, FY as 2016, Quarter as 1, Month as April, then it should `filter/return` the `Total i.e 100` for the given filters)

b. Similarly, I want to `return Sum of all the Totals`(ex: if I give Name as ABC, Dept as First, FY as 2016 - then it should `return sum of the required Total values(i.e 100+150=250)` for the given `FY 2016` only)

Please help me in this requirement, how can I achieve, Thanks.

I have tried below, but it is giving all the results for given Name(ex: If I give Name as ABC, then it is returning all the details ABC only)

```
return getData().then(res => {
            res.data.filter(customerDetails =>{

        if(customerDetails.Name === name && customerDetails.FY === fy && customerDetails.Quarter === quarter &&  customerDetails.Month === month &&  customerDetails.Dept === dept)
           agent.add(`Details: ${name}, Dept: ${customerDetails.Dept}, 
            FY: ${customerDetails.FY}, Quarter: ${customerDetails.Quarter}, Month: ${customerDetails.Month},
            Total: ${customerDetails.Total} `);
             });

             });
```

Comment: please add your code as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz added my trial code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do that. Filter data based on passed values, and then add `Total` values of filtered data to get final total.

```js
var data = [{ "Name": "ABC", "Dept": "First", "FY": "2016", "Quarter": "1", "Month": "April", "Total": "100" }, { "Name": "ABC", "Dept": "Second", "FY": "2017", "Quarter": "2", "Month": "May", "Total": "200" }, { "Name": "ABC", "Dept": "First", "FY": "2016", "Quarter": "1", "Month": "June", "Total": "150" }, { "Name": "DEF", "Dept": "First", "FY": "2016", "Quarter": "1", "Month": "April", "Total": "200" }, { "Name": "DEF", "Dept": "Second", "FY": "2017", "Quarter": "2", "Month": "May", "Total": "100" }, { "Name": "DEF", "Dept": "First", "FY": "2016", "Quarter": "1", "Month": "June", "Total": "500" }];

function getTotal(filters) {
  var total = 0;

  const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
    for (var key in filters) {
      if (item[key] != filters[key]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });

  filteredData.forEach(value => total += Number(value.Total));

  return total;
}

 console.log(getTotal({ "Name": "ABC", "Dept": "First", "FY": "2016" }));

 console.log(getTotal({"Name": "DEF" }));
```

Comment: I have tried the above, but Total is giving 0(empty response), I am not sure why, I am trying to access from Google Spreadsheet for dialogflow.

Comment: @Dhana - It might be that the numbers in your data are not strings but just numbers. In such case, performing strict inequality `!==` would fail even if the values are the same. Try using abstract inequality `!=` instead of strict inequality `!==`. Check out my edited code in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object with the wanted filter values and filter the array and return the sum of all `Total`.

```js
function getTotal(data, filters) {
    var f = Object.entries(filters);
    return data
        .filter(o => f.every(([k, v]) => o[k] == v))
        .reduce((s, { Total }) => s + +Total, 0);
}


var data = [{ Name: "ABC", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "April", Total: "100" }, { Name: "ABC", Dept: "Second", FY: "2017", Quarter: "2", Month: "May", Total: "200" }, { Name: "ABC", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "June", Total: "150" }, { Name: "DEF", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "April", Total: "200" }, { Name: "DEF", Dept: "Second", FY: "2017", Quarter: "2", Month: "May", Total: "100" }, { Name: "DEF", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "June", Total: "500" }];

console.log(getTotal(data, { Name: 'ABC', Dept: 'First', FY: 2016, Quarter: 1, Month: 'April' })); // 100
console.log(getTotal(data, { Name: 'ABC', Dept: 'First', FY: 2016 })); // 100 + 150 = 250
```

Comment: I have tried the above, but Total is giving 0(empty response), I am not sure why, I am trying to access from Google Spreadsheet for dialogflow.

Comment: maybe the numbers are not strings, as in the data above. you could try to use `==` instead of strict `===` conparison.