# TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined at getTotal() in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, find, reduce

From the below code, I want to get the value of Total based on my input values/filters. If I use `.filter()` method it is not working in my application(`getting empty response or 0`), but working in externally standalone page, I am not sure why. Please help me. Thanks.

With the below code, I am getting the error in my application: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined at getTotal()`

index.js:

```
function getTotal(data, filters) {

console.log(JSON.stringify(filters));//{"Name":"ABC","Dept":"First","FY":"2016","Quarter":"1","Month":"April"} 
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));//[{"Name":"ABC","Dept":"First","FY":"2016","Quarter":"1","Month":"April","Total":"1200"},{"Name":"ABC","Dept":"Second","FY":"2017","Quarter":"2","Month":"May","Total":"200"},{"Name":"ABC","Dept":"First","FY":"2016","Quarter":"1","Month":"June","Total":"150"},{"Name":"DEF","Dept":"First","FY":"2016","Quarter":"1","Month":"April","Total":"200"},{"Name":"DEF","Dept":"Second","FY":"2017","Quarter":"2","Month":"May","Total":"100"},{"Name":"DEF","Dept":"First","FY":"2016","Quarter":"1","Month":"June","Total":"500"}] 

    var f = Object.entries(filters);
    console.log("f is: "+f);// Name,ABC,Dept,First,FY,2016,Quarter,1,Month,April
    const test = data.find(o => f.every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v)).reduce((s, { Total }) => s + +Total, 0);
    return test;//Output should be: 100
}


var data = [{ Name: "ABC", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "April", Total: "100" }, { Name: "ABC", Dept: "Second", FY: "2017", Quarter: "2", Month: "May", Total: "200" }, { Name: "ABC", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "June", Total: "150" }, { Name: "DEF", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "April", Total: "200" }, { Name: "DEF", Dept: "Second", FY: "2017", Quarter: "2", Month: "May", Total: "100" }, { Name: "DEF", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "June", Total: "500" }];

console.log(getTotal(data, { Name: 'ABC', Dept: 'First', FY: '2016', Quarter: '1', Month: 'April' })); // shoud give: 100
```

Yes, got the answer now at: [How to return and get the sum of object properties based on given filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942587/how-to-return-and-get-the-sum-of-object-properties-based-on-given-filters/57942930?noredirect=1#comment102303460_57942930)

Comment: what do you think `data.find(o => f.every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v))` does? what do you think f.every returns, or data.find ... data.find will return a single element of data or undefined

Comment: I want to iterate and find/filter my object and reducing to Total value based on my input filters.

Comment: why you have reduce ? find will return an object use that if found, access property directly

Comment: @Guna find will always return the first element which satisfies condition

Comment: `data.find` change to `data.filter`

Comment: @JaromandaX, if I use .filter(), it is not working in my application, but it is working in a staandalone page. I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Would you describe "it is not working" with a little more detail? And at any rate `find` definitively won't work.

Comment: @CodeManiac, yes, but please let me know how can I get my Total value on my filters.

Comment: @mbojko, yes I agree with you - find won't work. but how can I iterate over my filters and can get my Total ?

Comment: then you're doing something wrong in the REAL code - because the code you posted works just fine with filter

Comment: @Guna you can access that found object and get the key's value you're looking for, i.e `...find().Total`,

Comment: at a guess ... `data` is either, NOT an array of objects, or perhaps it's some other object coming from some database request, perhaps a promise, or some such - please show in the question how `data` is obtained in the real code

Comment: @JaromandaX, yess i am returning as promise, I just edited the post for that, Actually I cannot post code fully.

Comment: well, since you're calling your function inside .then, I would assume `res.data` is actual data - have you tried using console.log in there to inspect the what `res.data` is, and what `filter` is? perhaps the issue is that the values in `filter` is not correct ... e.g. `console.log(res.data.slice(0, 2))` (just inspect the first two entries, make sure they are in the expected format) and `console.log(filter)` - just before you call the funciton

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Array.prototype.filter` instead of `Array.prototype.find` as it returns an *array* instead of a single object from your array. 
Objects don't have a `reduce` method arrays do:

```js
function getTotal(data, filters) {
   var f = Object.entries(filters);
   const test = data.filter(o => f.every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v)).reduce((s, { Total }) => s + +Total, 0);
   return test;//Output should be: 100
}


var data = [{ Name: "ABC", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "April", Total: "100" }, { Name: "ABC", Dept: "Second", FY: "2017", Quarter: "2", Month: "May", Total: "200" }, { Name: "ABC", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "June", Total: "150" }, { Name: "DEF", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "April", Total: "200" }, { Name: "DEF", Dept: "Second", FY: "2017", Quarter: "2", Month: "May", Total: "100" }, { Name: "DEF", Dept: "First", FY: "2016", Quarter: "1", Month: "June", Total: "500" }];

console.log(getTotal(data, { Name: 'ABC', Dept: 'First', FY: '2016', Quarter: '1', Month: 'April' })); // shoud give: 100
```

Comment: if I use filter method, it is not workig in my application, as I mentioned in the question

Comment: @Guna it is hard to tell without looking at the other aspects of your application why exactly `filter` is not working, you cannot invoke `reduce `on the object returned from `find`. The `find` method will return you the first object it finds from your array so it should not be used for filtering.

Comment: @Guna what is error you are getting when you use `filter` ?

Comment: if I use .filter() method, I am getting the empty response i.e 0

Comment: @Guna - please update your question and show where `data` is coming from - it's clearly not hardcoded like in the question

Comment: @Guna I am guessing the filter is returning an empty array so you get 0 as a result. Check the data of the second object parameter which is passed in the `getTotal` function.

Comment: If you click on *Run code snippet*, you'll find that `filter` _is_ working. So the problem is somewhere else, somewhere you're not sharing.

Comment: @FullstackGuy, data is coming from API, second parameter is giving like: {"Name":"ABC","Dept":"First","FY":"2016","Quarter":"1","Month":"April"}  in getTotal() function

Comment: @FullstackGuy, yes it is fine now, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942587/how-to-return-and-get-the-sum-of-object-properties-based-on-given-filters/57942930?noredirect=1#comment102303460_57942930 . Thanks a lot for your help !